# multiple activities are not in one app android studio

Tags: java, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

My multiple activity show different app and not mix in one app
how to fix it , could you help or maybe i forgot something in my code
here that problem i gave red square of that problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S06lw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look Like That this Is Your Directory Problem & Not Of Code
Make Sure That All The Activities Are In Same Package of Your Application.
And Also Check Activity In **AndroidMeinfist.xml** , It Should Contain All The Activities

If You Still Didn't Find Solutions , Try Me To Share Your Code

Comment: it show the all activity when i was made wth Launcher so the diffirent activity going to be Launcher and i just have to erase that Thanks for soloution of manifest problem

Comment: Glade It Helped You 